# two actionButton(s) that renders different pages

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app (apologies in advance for the length but wanted to provide a reprex):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
data('mtcars')

ui <- navbarPage("Test App",
                 tabPanel("Scatter Plot",
                          fluidPage(
                            ## Side Panel
                            fluidRow(
                              column(width = 3,
                                     selectInput(inputId = "cyl", 
                                                 label = "cylender", 
                                                 choices = c(4, 6, 8), 
                                                 selected = 4), 
                                     actionButton(inputId = "load", 
                                                  label =  "Load", 
                                                  width = "100%")
                              ),
                              column(width = 8,
                                     tabPanel("Scatter Plot",
                                              plotOutput("plot1", height = "90%", width = "90%"))
                              )))),
                 tabPanel("Data Table",
                          fluidRow(column(width = 12, div(dataTableOutput("plot2"))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cars = eventReactive(eventExpr = input$load, valueExpr = {
    res =  mtcars %>% filter(cyl == input$cyl)
    return(res)  
  })
  
  getGraph = function() {
      dat = cars()
      p = ggplot(dat, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
        geom_point()
      return(p)
    }
    
    getDataTable = function(input) {
      dat = cars()
      return(dat)
    }
  
  output$plot1 = renderPlot({
    getGraph()
  }, height = function(){
    session$clientData$output_plot1_width })

  output$plot2 = renderDT(
    getDataTable()
    ,
    class = "display nowrap compact", 
    filter = "top", 
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE))}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to add a second button next to 'Load' called 'Load Data Table' that would take the user right to the second tab. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `updateNavbarPage` to select the `tabPanel` you want to display. For this, you have to include an `id` in your `navbarPage`. I also changed your `car` reactive so that it also updates if you click on the "Load Data Table" button:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
data('mtcars')

ui <- navbarPage("Test App",
                 id = "main_navbar",
                 tabPanel("Scatter Plot",
                          fluidPage(
                            ## Side Panel
                            fluidRow(
                              column(width = 3,
                                     selectInput(inputId = "cyl", 
                                                 label = "cylender", 
                                                 choices = c(4, 6, 8), 
                                                 selected = 4), 
                                     actionButton(inputId = "load", 
                                                  label =  "Load", 
                                                  width = "100%"),
                                     actionButton(inputId = "table",
                                                  label = "Load Data Table",
                                                  width = "100%")
                              ),
                              column(width = 8,
                                     tabPanel("Scatter Plot",
                                              plotOutput("plot1", height = "90%", width = "90%"))
                              )))),
                 tabPanel("Data Table",
                          fluidRow(column(width = 12, div(dataTableOutput("plot2"))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cars = eventReactive(eventExpr = c(input$load, input$table), valueExpr = {
    res =  mtcars %>% filter(cyl == input$cyl)
    return(res)  
  },
  ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  getGraph = function() {
    dat = cars()
    p = ggplot(dat, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
      geom_point()
    return(p)
  }
  
  getDataTable = function(input) {
    dat = cars()
    return(dat)
  }
  
  output$plot1 = renderPlot({
    getGraph()
  }, height = function(){
    session$clientData$output_plot1_width })
  
  output$plot2 = renderDT(
    getDataTable()
    ,
    class = "display nowrap compact", 
    filter = "top", 
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
  
  observeEvent(input$table, {
    updateNavbarPage(
      session,
      inputId = "main_navbar",
      selected = "Data Table"
    )
  })
  
  }


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit**
I've added `ignoreInit = TRUE` to the `eventReactive` so that it doesn't create the data.frame on startup.

Comment: Thanks, but this starts up with the scatter plot already loaded (before even pressing either of the buttons). Is there any way to make it so it starts up blank?

Comment: I've added `ignoreInit = TRUE` so that nothing happens on startup. Interestingly, the `c()` triggers the execution of the observer even for `c(input$load)`

Comment: Another follow-up--I noticed that if I 'Load Data Table' and then navigate back to the line graph tab it is already rendered. Reason I'm asking this question is because rendering the plot takes much longer than the data table, so if it's working on it in the background it kind of defeats the purpose of having a 'Load Data Table' button